# Weird qt parse error "Parse Error ('')"

Tags: ubuntu, qt-creator, qmake

everyone.
I installed qt creator 2.4.1 under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS using its software centre.
The qmake shows the following weird error:

```
/usr/bin/qmake-qt4 -spec /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o Makefile test3.pro
/home/paul/Documents/workplace/test3/test3.pro:1: Parse Error ('')
Error processing project file: test3.pro
```

A parse error of no error ......
But the error is not presented when a new project is just created without editing the the pro file at all.

Pro file editing includes any thing such as typing a space in the comment or changing a character to itself.

The error has no relationship with the content of the code or the pro file.

Comment: Can you include the top few lines of test3.pro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the warning refers to a nonexistent or invisible character on line 1, this might be a [Unicode BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), and qmake might not be able to read it for whatever reason.

Try dumping `test3.pro` using `hexdump -C test3.pro` — is the first character an ASCII printable character (between hex 0x20 and 0x7e), or is it outside of that range (such as 0xef,0xbb,0xbf)?  If it's outside that range, try opening `test3.pro` in a Unicode-compliant text editor, and saving it without a BOM.

Comment: Thank you ! I set the default encoding to UTF-8 and add BOM if not present, but it seems qmake was complaining about that. Not very compatible is it :D